# Branch.io Track Referral without rewards

Tags: branch.io

**Scenario**: User(Primary) sends out an app download link to his friend & his friend downloads the app using the same link. When the primary user opens the app again, how can he get to know that his referral was successful (True or false is enough).

**Question**: How can I do this using branch.io?

**My assumption**:

1. createBranchUniversalObject
2. generateShortUrl & share with friend (Now friend installs)
3. whenever user open the app use “getFirstReferringParams” to track the referral

Correct me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex with Branch.io here: this is a great question. Our referral feature is only designed to handle credit tracking out of the box, but you can add a bit of custom handling to implement identity tracking the way you describe.

The prerequisite for this to work is that you are using the Branch [setIdentity()](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/growth-attribution/guide/ios/#setting-identities) method for all of your users at the point when they register for a unique account in your app. The flow looks something like this:

1. User A downloads the your app.
2. User A registers for a unique account in your app and you trigger the setIdentity() method.
3. User A creates a sharing link and sends it to User B. Branch automatically records User A's identity info in the data for that link.
4. User B opens the link and downloads the app. All the data for the link (including User A's identity) is returned as part of the Branch init() call. You store this data locally until...
5. ...user B registers for a unique account in your app and you trigger the setIdentity() method.
6. You send a message back to your own server and queue it up to inform User A that their referral was accepted.

If you are also tracking referral credits, you will need to set up those rules too. Documentation for that process is on [this page](https://dev.branch.io/features/referral-programs/guide/ios/).

Hope that helps!